# FailedPreconditionError Keras

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to apply mask to the part of the screen that i capture. `screen = grab_screen(region=(0,40,800,640))`. Then, i apply my function that is contained in  another file. `screen = road_lines_image(screen)`(that is how i import it `from linedetect import road_lines_image`). In another file, i have a following function.

```
def road_lines_image(imageIn):
    #crop to 720x1280, img[y: y + h, x: x + w], 300:940
    image = imageIn[230:950, 0:1280]
    image = imresize(image, (640, 1280, 3))

    # Get image ready for feeding into model
    small_img = imresize(image, (80, 160, 3))
    small_img = np.array(small_img)

    small_img = small_img[None,:,:,:]

    # Make prediction with neural network (un-normalize value by multiplying by 255)
    prediction = model.predict(small_img)[0] * 255
```

(function is longer but the last line is where i get an error. After my function call from the main file, i get an error

```
FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value Final/kernel
         [[{{node Final/kernel/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Final/kernel)]]
```

I tried to run following code from the file where road_lines_image is

```
img = cv2.imread("road-traffic-car-981035.jpg")
img  = road_lines_image(img)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This code works perfect and i get a desired output. I encounter the problem when i run from the main file.

Comment: Where do you initialize `model`??

Comment: It is outside of the function

Comment: Are you using tensorflow backend for keras??

Comment: Solved! Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I declared model outside of the function. I added it inside and now it works perfectly!